# What are some shortcuts for doing faster calculations?

Tags: calculator, error-propagation

In my way I face a lot of problems in solving the time consuming expressions sometimes I got the correct answer but sometimes not so I had so repeart the whole process again.
Approximation is good but don't work well if we want significance in answer and we can't carry calculator in examination.

Answer (score 1):

Start with a $20\times 20
$ multiplication table and memorize it.

Then start with memorizing the square of all 2 digit numbers.

If you start being friendly with numbers you will be amazed how well the numbers treat you.

Comment: In the 19th century in England, children were taught to memorize the mult. table up to 20x20 (which explains one of the "jokes" in Alice In Wonderland)..... See also The Tractenburg peed System Of Basic Mathematics.

Comment: A little algebra helps too. E,g. 79x79=(80-1)(80-1)=6400-160+1)=6241, or 79x67=(80-1)(70-3)=5600-70-240+3=5293.